# rebuild the tree generated by GBM package in R manually

Tags: r, boosting

I've used the gbm in R to generate a model. Although I can use predict.gbm to fit the model on new data set, I want to know the detailed step of gbm to calculate the prediction, beacuse I need to write such code in C++ for other application.

I used

```
    tree <- pretty.gbm.tree(model, i.tree=1)
```

and it shows:

```
    SplitVar SplitCodePred LeftNode RightNode MissingNode ErrorReduction Weight    Prediction
    0        22  1.443225e-04        1        26          30      529.36379 132010 -5.171610e-06
    1        48 -7.033773e-04        2        18          25      351.30874  91916 -4.234042e-04
    2        32 -1.581934e-03        3         4          17      294.59416   4239 -3.235046e-03
    3        -1  4.159611e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    478  4.159611e-03
    4        47  2.370844e-02        5        12          16      168.32051   3761 -4.174862e-03
    5        30 -6.295779e-01        6         7          11      105.65495   3525 -3.627476e-03
    6        -1  4.671729e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    147  4.671729e-03
    7        16 -5.710531e-01        8         9          10       98.05341   3378 -3.988632e-03
    8        -1 -2.225353e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000   1631 -2.225353e-03
    9        -1 -5.634830e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000   1747 -5.634830e-03
    10       -1 -3.988632e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000   3378 -3.988632e-03
    11       -1 -3.627476e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000   3525 -3.627476e-03
    12       43 -2.381094e-02       13        14          15      135.69243    236 -1.235085e-02
    13       -1 -6.450770e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    147 -6.450770e-03
    14       -1 -2.209593e-02       -1        -1          -1        0.00000     89 -2.209593e-02
    15       -1 -1.235085e-02       -1        -1          -1        0.00000    236 -1.235085e-02
    16       -1 -4.174862e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000   3761 -4.174862e-03
    17       -1 -3.235046e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000   4239 -3.235046e-03
    18        0  8.715281e-02       19        23          24      128.75576  87677 -2.874671e-04
    19       36  3.360935e-01       20        21          22      106.12050  51342 -6.098461e-04
    20       -1 -8.775861e-04       -1        -1          -1        0.00000  38121 -8.775861e-04
    21       -1  1.621467e-04       -1        -1          -1        0.00000  13221  1.621467e-04
    22       -1 -6.098461e-04       -1        -1          -1        0.00000  51342 -6.098461e-04
    23       -1  1.680601e-04       -1        -1          -1        0.00000  36335  1.680601e-04
    24       -1 -2.874671e-04       -1        -1          -1        0.00000  87677 -2.874671e-04
    25       -1 -4.234042e-04       -1        -1          -1        0.00000  91916 -4.234042e-04
    26       48  1.212169e-04       27        28          29      118.94817  40094  9.536318e-04
    27       -1  4.416651e-04       -1        -1          -1        0.00000  21287  4.416651e-04
    28       -1  1.533109e-03       -1        -1          -1        0.00000  18807  1.533109e-03
    29       -1  9.536318e-04       -1        -1          -1        0.00000  40094  9.536318e-04
    30       -1 -5.171610e-06       -1        -1          -1        0.00000 132010 -5.171610e-06
```

Then I use the first 10 samples of the original data set to calculate the prediction:

```
    pred <- predict.gbm(model, newdata=train.sample[1:10,],n.trees=1)
    pred
```

it shows:

```
    [1] -0.01897030 -0.01897030 -0.01897030 -0.01896438 -0.01896438 -0.02001003 -0.02001003 -0.02001003 -0.02001003 -0.02001003
```

My understanding of gbm is that the predicted values would be one of the values of a leaf. But these fitted values are not shown in the original tree. I check the code of predict.gbm, it shows the core part of it is to call a compiled function gbm_pred, whose detailed is hidden.Does anybody know how to reconstruct a gbm regression step-by-step in R?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Before the first iteration, gbm subtracts out the mean of the response variable. You need to add the mean to the terminal node values to get the final prediction. See the following example:

```
library(gbm)
data("Orange")
d <- Orange
out <- gbm(circumference~age,data=d,n.trees=1,shrinkage=1,bag.frac=1,interaction.depth = 2)
p   <- predict(out,newdata=d,n.trees=1)
unique(p)

# 60.66667 139.90000 174.60000

tree <- pretty.gbm.tree(out)
tree$Prediction[tree$SplitVar==-1] + out$initF

# 60.66667 139.90000 174.60000 157.25000 115.85714
```

The last two nodes are the 'missing' nodes respectively.

However, you don't have to re-implement gbm functions yourself. You might try using GBM C/C++ source directly for your application, i.e. just calling `gbm_pred` directly.

See the most recent version of the source here https://github.com/gbm-developers/gbm

And the source for gbm currently on CRAN here https://github.com/harrysouthworth/gbm

All the C/C++ source is available in the `/src` directories.